# Error de persistencia de fechas con jsf jpa eclipseLink ejb

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa, ejb

Estoy tratando de guardar un rango de fechas y fijando el año en una tabla en MySQL, corro la aplicación y esta funciona bien con otras tablas, pero al guardar el periodo me arroja el error:

> INFORMACIÓN:   ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='no puede
>   ser null', propertyPath=anio, rootBeanClass=class com.modelo.Periodo,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>
> INFORMACIÓN:   ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='no puede
>   ser null', propertyPath=fIni, rootBeanClass=class com.modelo.Periodo,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>
> INFORMACIÓN:   ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='no puede
>   ser null', propertyPath=fFin, rootBeanClass=class com.modelo.Periodo,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}

Las clases que tengo son:

```
Entity modelo:

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "periodo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "Periodo.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Periodo p"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Periodo.findByIdPeriodo", query = "SELECT p FROM Periodo p WHERE p.idPeriodo = :idPeriodo"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Periodo.findByAnio", query = "SELECT p FROM Periodo p WHERE p.anio = :anio"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Periodo.findByFIni", query = "SELECT p FROM Periodo p WHERE p.fIni = :fIni"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Periodo.findByFFin", query = "SELECT p FROM Periodo p WHERE p.fFin = :fFin")})
public class Periodo implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id_periodo")
  private Integer idPeriodo;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "anio")
  private Date anio;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "f_ini")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date fIni;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "f_fin")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date fFin;


  public Periodo() {
  }

  public Periodo(Integer idPeriodo) {
    this.idPeriodo = idPeriodo;
  }

  public Periodo(Integer idPeriodo, Date anio, Date fIni, Date fFin) {
    this.idPeriodo = idPeriodo;
    this.anio = anio;
    this.fIni = fIni;
    this.fFin = fFin;
  }
```

Con sus `getter` y `setter`

Un abstract facade con JPA eclipse Link.

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

  private Class<T> entityClass;

  public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
  }

  protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

  public void create(T entity) {
        try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        // Aqui tira los errores de constraint
        for (ConstraintViolation actual : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            System.out.println(actual.toString());
        }
    }
  }
```

Un PeriodoFacade:

```
import com.mintic.siped.dao.AbstractFacade;
import com.mintic.siped.modelo.Periodo;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class PeriodoFacade extends AbstractFacade<Periodo> implements PeriodoFacadeLocal {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SipedPU")
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
  }

  public PeriodoFacade() {
    super(Periodo.class);
  }
```

Un ManagedBean para el periodo:

```
import com.mintic.siped.dao.PeriodoFacadeLocal;
import com.mintic.siped.modelo.Periodo;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "periodoControl")
@SessionScoped
public class PeriodoControl implements Serializable {

  @EJB
  private PeriodoFacadeLocal periodoEjb;
  @Inject
  private Periodo periodo;
  private List<Periodo> listaPeriodos;

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of periodoControl
   */
  public PeriodoControl() {
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    listaPeriodos = periodoEjb.findAll();
  }

  public Periodo getPeriodo() {
    return periodo;
  }

  public void setPeriodo(Periodo periodo) {
    this.periodo = periodo;
  }

  public List<Periodo> getListaPeriodos() {
    return listaPeriodos;
  }

  public void setListaPeriodos(List<Periodo> listaPeriodos) {
    this.listaPeriodos = listaPeriodos;
  }

  public void registrar() {
    try {
      periodoEjb.create(periodo);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Aviso", "Periodo añadido Exitosamente"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Error", "Ha ocurrido un problema guardando el nuevo registro"));
    }
  }
```

Y una vista por facelets con primefaces:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="./../templates/Principal.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="frmPeriodo">
      <h1><h:outputText value="Añadir periodos para la evaluación" style="color: #427589; text-align: center"/></h1>
      <br/>
      <p:fieldset legend="Módulo Periodos">
        <p:panelGrid id="pgFrmPeriodo" columns="3">
          <p:outputLabel value="Año a evaluar:" for="anio" />
          <p:inputText id="anio" value="#{periodoControl.periodo.anio}" required="true" requiredMessage="El Año es requerido.">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" for="anio" timeZone="America/Bogota"/>
          </p:inputText>
          <p:message for="anio"/>

          <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de inicio o Apertura:" for="FIni" />
          <p:calendar id="FIni" value="#{periodoControl.periodo.FIni}" locale="es" 
                      navigator="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" required="true" 
                      requiredMessage="Se necesita una fecha de inicio." timeZone="America/Bogota" />
          <p:message for="FIni"/>

          <p:outputLabel value="Fecha de cierre o Fin:" for="FFin" />
          <p:calendar id="FFin" value="#{periodoControl.periodo.FFin}" locale="es" 
                      navigator="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" required="true" 
                      requiredMessage="Se necesita una fecha de finalización." timeZone="America/Bogota" />
          <p:message for="FFin"/>

        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:separator/>
        <p:commandButton id="Guardar" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Guardar" actionListener="#{periodoControl.registrar()}" 
                         update="frmPeriodo"/>
        <p:commandButton id="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-cancel" value="Cancelar"/>

        <p:separator/>
        <p:dataTable value="#{periodoControl.listaPeriodos}" var="per">
          <p:column headerText="Nombre">
            <h:outputText value="#{per.anio}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Cód. Dane">
            <h:outputText value="#{per.FIni}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Zona">
            <h:outputText value="#{per.FFin}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Acciones">
            <p:commandButton value="Editar" actionListener="#{periodoControl.editar()}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" actionListener="#{periodoControl.eliminar()}" />
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

La verdad esta misma estructura la he manejado para otras tablas, pero con esta es la única con la que me presenta el error y no me guarda la información.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola Reinaldo, bienvenido al sitio. Te recomiendo visitar: [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego edita tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida y te puedan ayudar adecuadamente

Comment: no se cual seria el mínimo necesario para publicar ya que no soy experto... espero que alguien pueda identificar mi necesidad

Answer (score 0):

En tu clase `Periodo` declaraste:

```
private Date anio;
private Date fIni;
private Date fFin;
```

pero en la vista:

```
<p:inputText id="anio" ...
<p:calendar id="FIni" ...
<p:calendar id="FFin" ...
```

¿Ves la diferencia? En la vista empiezan con mayúscula y en la clase no están así. Aunque me parece también podrían necesitar un atributo `name` en la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista el error Si es con las mayusculas pero NO en el id `<p:calendar id="FIni" ...` como te sugiere @abrahamhs, sino en el value,este el valor que realmente guarda el componente una vez que el user interactua con el. El id es solo un id para el componente en el codigo html que se genera, y no tiene nada que ver con los datos que maneja el componente.

Tu pones

`value="#{periodoControl.periodo.FIni}"
value="#{periodoControl.periodo.FFin}`

mientras que el codigo debería ser:

`value="#{periodoControl.periodo.fIni}"
value="#{periodoControl.periodo.fFin}`

como declaras en la @Entity.